# How do I insert values from one table into another without a value to inner join them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A has a single field.
Table B has many fields.

I want to copy each value from Table A to a row on Table B but I have no values with which to join the two tables.

It doesn't matter which row in B each value in A goes into as long as each value in Table A only appears once in Table B.

I do not want to use loops.

Comment: Please Provide the Sample Data

Comment: You need to have some row ID. Otherwise when you run the script twice it would insert duplicate values.

Comment: A.FKID (INT)
B.PKID (INT), B.FKID (INT)

I want to copy A.FKID into B.FKID.

Neither table has a reference to the other.
Both tables are temporary (data will be used to update table C and then discarded)

Comment: Many thanks. Using both the examples below I managed to do what I needed.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a row number to each of the two tables, and then do  an update join:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) rn
    FROM TableA
),
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM TableB
)
UPDATE t2
SET col = t1.col
FROM cte2 t2
INNER JOIN cte1 t1
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

This solution makes several assumptions, including that `TableB` already has a destination column `col` for the data coming from the first `TableA` table's single column, and that the types match in both tables.  It also assumes that `TableB` has more rows than `TableA` to fit the data from `TableB`.  If not, data would be lost.